# Algorithm for distributing members over activites (with individual preferences)

Tags: java, algorithm, distribution

So in my school we have a day where everybody participates in different activities.
Each projects can have like 10 members. The whole day is divided in 2 or 3 different blocks, in which the pupils assigned to the activity change.(So in block 1 pupil x takes part in activity a and in the second block in activity d).
Before this day starts, we give make lists in which each pupil can tell us his 3 (or 4) favorite activities (he only takes part in two of them, these again are ordered from most "favorite" to least) in which he wants to take part.
Now our job is to assign these pupils in a way that we have the best overall satisfaction among the pupils (so everybody did more or less did get his/her chosen activities).What would be a good algorithm to solve this ?(I'm quite familiar with programming (especially java), so the approach would be enough too (although some (pseudo-)code would be great too:) )
Is there any way to do this, apart from calculating such a "satisfaction" value for each possible solution?

An optional feature would be that if someone can't get in to his/her project, they would get into a similar on (also this sounds kind of sexist, you could for example rate how "female"/"male" this activity is and choose similar activities according to this scale)

I'm hope this question is fits into stackexchange, if it is totally off-topic I would be happy to tell me about a more suitable stack.

Looking forward to your suggestions,
John

Comment: are there any minimum no of pupil needed for project to happen or 1 is sufficient

Comment: There would have to be more than just one or two in a group:)

Answer (score 0):

If the students are ranking each of their favorite activities (1-4) then it's simple to assign those activities a weight (1-4). You group everyone that weights a certain activity at a certain level and compare the number of students to the number of activities. If there's more students than spots the method of choosing is up in the air. I would say random for fairness or if you want to get fancy you can track it from day to day so that everyone gets a chance to participate in a favorite activity.

If there are more slots than students then you could poll for people who rate it a 3 and so on down the line.

That seems like a fair place to start at least.

Comment: That is a good idea to start, but how would determine who has to go to which activity in which block if not everybody can take part in all there two most favorite activities (you also have to determine who has to participate in what in which block,so that the overall satisfaction is the best)

Comment: Well if someone misses on one activity you could raise the weight of their next highest (3 becomes 4 etc) increasing their chance of getting into a higher rated activity.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an algorithm for you but there is a package which will do much of the job for you. The site is http://www.optaplanner.org/ and it is part of the Drools project.

Configuring the application requires some work. By the time you finish the configuration you will have gotten some hint as to how hard the task is, and why no simple algorithm will do the job.

Comment: do you have any idea how I could introduce the problem with the different blocks (and the weighted assignment)? Which type of problem would i have to configure?

Comment: Hmm. I didn't read your question in enough detail. If each student can perform 2 activities, why not assign number 1 and 2 on the list to each student for their first and second block? That would maximize satisfaction.

Comment: but that only works if everybody can get his/her favorite activities ... but if there isn't enough space that alone isn't sufficent

Comment: So, you have space constraints, project group size constraints, project activity constraints and weighting metrics. These are all things you have to configure (and program). Optaplanner first does an allocation that satisfies hard constraints and then allows calculation of one or more metrics that need to be min/maxed. A hard constraint might be "all students have at least one activity"; a metric might be "maximize satisfaction".